# Is there a way to Commit and Push changes to multiple Git repositories in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

I have a VS2022 solution that contains multiple projects.  There are 9 different Git repositories involved.  I can use the 'Git Changes' tab to 'Commit All Repos', but I do not see a way to commit AND push all repos.  I end up using the 'Git Repository' window to push each outgoing commit individually.  I would like to be able to do them all in a single UI operation.

Comment: You could open up the terminal (even within vs) and type `git push --all`

Comment: @Torge Rosendahl - Only seems to push the changes in the one repo that is located in the folder that is the current directory of the  terminal window.

Comment: Okay so they are different repos within the same project directory? Or are they all just seperaten projects?

Comment: From the command line, you must run one `git push` per Git repository. Whether VS or VSCode have ways to do this with a single click or keystroke or whatever is up to those programs.

Comment: @Torge Rosendahl - Multiple repos, some with a single project in them and some with multiple projects in them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as of VS 17.4.2, you can press the 'Push' (up arrow) button on the 'Git Changes' tab and it pushes all the branches that have already been Committed.  I don't know if this is new behavior or not, but I discovered that it works today.  Not as nice as 'Commit and Push All' would be, but 2 steps is better than 10.